# Python number list permutations with unexpected results

Tags: python, list, permutation

I am attempting to take a list of numbers 0-9 inclusive and return all the permutations of the list.  I have come up with two different functions that return the expected result to a certain extent but, neither is exactly what I am aiming for.  Here is one that returns the correct results for one cycle:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def test(x):
  place_holder = 9
  count = 9
  print x
  while count > 1:
    old_x = x[count]
    x[count] = x[count-1]
    x[count-1] = old_x
    count -= 1
    print x
    if count == 1:
      x.sort()
      place_holder -= 1
      count = place_holder
```

Returns:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Though when I use another list in the permutation, it gives unexpected results:

```
x = [1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Where it goes through the nine cycle properly then goes back to 0-9.  So I could see this is because of the x.sort() call.  So I changed this function to this:

```
def exp_test(x):
  static = []
  for i in x:
    static.append(i)
  place_holder = 9
  count = 9
  print x
  while count > 1:
    old_x = x[count]
    x[count] = x[count-1]
    x[count-1] = old_x
    count -= 1
    print x
    if count == 1:
      x = static
      place_holder -= 1
      count = place_holder
```

Now this works fine until the shift of the seven and it goes to every second number.  I figure the count got mixed up but, I go through and don't see it?

Comment: Why not just use `itertools.permutations()`? http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying `x = static` in the last `if` statement to `x = static[:]`.  The problem is that you are simply rebinding the name `x` to the same list that `static` is bound to.  You really want to make a copy of what `static` is bound to instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help!  Now I know if I were to assign `static = x`, then if I change x, static changes too.  I didn't realize that this works in reverse as well.  If I'm not saying that right could you let me know :D

Comment: I put in the lines for appending the items in x to a new list static specifically for that reason not knowing it works the other way around too.  Now I could take that out and just put `static = x[:]` and in the if `x = static[:]`, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be

```
from itertools import permutations
```

but if you must write it yourself, the usual solution is recursive:

```
def permutations(seq):
    _len = len(seq)
    if _len:
        if _len==1:
            yield seq
        else:
            for p in permutations(seq[1:]):
                for i in range(_len):
                    yield p[:i] + seq[0:1] + p[i:]
```

**Edit:** well, the Euler problem requires a different approach altogether... the trick is not to generate all permutations up to 1,000,000 (which would be far too slow), but to calculate what the millionth permutation must be. There are n! ways to arrange n items - you can recursively use this on the tail of the sequence to figure out how many subsequences have to be rearranged to get to the millionth arrangement, and from that work out what the arrangement must be.

You need to write something more like

```
def nth_arrangement(seq, n):
    # you have to figure this bit out!
```

Comment: Hey Bothwell, I appreciate the response.  Like I said in the comment above, I tried to does this with barely any background knowledge of permutations and a question that could have been more explicit on how the ordering should go.  I've come up with several different sequencing functions that I believed was what they wanted :| .

Comment: @tijko: ok... so what was the original question, exactly?

Comment: @Bothwell: well it is a project euler question, so I was really hesitant to ask for help that would solve it for me.  It was to give the one millionth permutation of 0-9(inclusive).  With the example being [0,1,2], [0,2,1], [1,0,2], [1,2,0], [2,0,1], [2,1,0].  So I first started cycle the second to first number out instead of outside in.